# Building a project with Maven in Codenvy

Tags: java, maven, build, codenvy

I am new to Maven and Codenvy. Trying to build a simple Jar project there. The build fails everytime, although I seem to include all necessary dependencies in pom.xml file.

Here's the project: https://codenvy.com/factory?v=1.0&pname=simplejar&wname=ivantsoft&vcs=git&vcsurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcodenvy.com%2Fgit%2F16%2F81%2F89%2Fworkspacepyk15s4hwbfabmg6%2Fsimplejar&idcommit=2af3588e343317907905b306d7faa3db5674d068&action=openproject&ptype=Jar

In my pom.xml I have:

```
<repositories> 
    <repository> 
      <id>biojava-maven-repo</id> 
      <name>BioJava repository</name> 
      <url>http://www.biojava.org/download/maven/</url>       
    </repository> 
  </repositories>
```

...

```
<dependency> 
      <groupId>org.biojava</groupId> 
      <artifactId>biojava3-core</artifactId> 
      <version>3.0.6</version> 
      <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency>
```

...

And in my java file I have: 
...

```
import org.biojava3.core.sequence;
```

...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You say the "build fails". What's the error message?

Comment: package org.biojava3.core does not exist

Comment: Please post the entire message. Are you sure that you only need `biojava3-core` in the `test` scope?

Comment: Part of the problem is that your import is wrong; `org.biojava3.core.sequence` is a package, and you need to import either a specific class from it or `org.biojava3.core.sequence.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Link is outdated.

> INVALID FACTORY URL

The question is to be closed with what chrylis said:

> Part of the problem is that your import is wrong; org.biojava3.core.sequence is a package, and you need to import either a specific class from it or org.biojava3.core.sequence.*.